# How does an incoming SSH connection request to a public IP address of a LAN with multiple machines (thus multiple SSH servers) get directed correctly?

Tags: ssh, ip, lan, nat, wan

Let's say I have two machines `mA` (Private ip: 192.168.0.3) and `mB` (Private ip: 192.168.0.4) within the same LAN whos public IP address is `2.2.2.2`. These machines both have users with common username `root`. Additionally, `mA` has user `uA` and `mB` has user `uB`.

I understand how `ssh` communication from `mA` or `mB` to another public IP `3.3.3.3` works. SSH from `mA port 22` creates a NAT table in the router which corresponds to `2.2.2.2 port 22` as source address. So any incoming reply from ssh requests from `3.3.3.3` to `2.2.2.2 port 22` can be reverse translated to `mA port 22`. This is possible because of the existence of `NAT table entry for mA`.

Now, if any other server outside the LAN tries to `ssh` to `mB` using `ssh root@2.2.2.2`. How does the router know which machine in the LAN to send this SSH request? (Since there is nothing to identify `mB` in NAT table now. And both `mA` and `mB` have root).

Is it different from what happens when you try to `ssh uB@2.2.2.2` where user `uB` only exists in `mB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outgoing connections**

```
on mA: ssh 3.3.3.3
```

This creates a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) table entry on the router with the following connection information

```
Source-IP   IP of mA
Source-Port >1024
Dest-IP     3.3.3.3
Dest-Port   22
```

The Source-IP is NATed to `2.2.2.2` and every time a packet with the above connection information (Source-IP is the NATed Source-IP) arrives at the router, the NATed Source-IP is translated back to the IP of `mA` and the packet is then forwarded to `mA`.

**Incoming connections**

For incoming connections, there is no connection information available at the router, this means, the router doesn't know what to do with a packet that has

```
Dest-IP     2.2.2.2
Dest-Port   22
```

in the TCP/IP header, assuming that the router itself is not reachable via SSH. Routers therefore have the ability to define so called [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) rules. A port forwarding rule has the form of

```
[Dest-IP:]Dest-Port  -->  Real-Dest-IP:Real-Dest-Port
```

If the router accepts more IP addresses the port forwarding rule can also distinguish between different Dest-IPs.

So in your case you have to create two port forwarding rules, one for `mA` and one for `mB`.

```
  22  -->  mA:22
2222  -->  mB:22
```

Unfortunately you have to connect to different ports from outside to get access to your servers.

With this rules the ssh commands for accessing your servers are the following:

```
mA: ssh 2.2.2.2
mB: ssh -p 2222 2.2.2.2
```

BTW: For security reasons, it is not advisable to access your servers directly as `root`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Thanks also for the endnote.
So, the port forwarding rules have to manually set? And there is no way for the router to know which machine to send it to unless I do not set the port forwarding rules? What happens in the situation of the above question - when such `ssh` request does arrive in the absence of the `port forwarding rules`?

So, when there is only one machine say `mA` with ssh enabled on port 22, the router can automatically send that any ssh request to port 22 of `mA`, right?

Comment: Also, IPv6 address is better way of connecting to the machine in the case mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: In the absence of a port forwarding rule the system who has the `2.2.2.2` assigned, the router, would process the incoming packet itself. If it has a ssh daemon running, it would process the packet, that means responding to a ssh connection request and if not it will discard the packet, either silently or sending an `icmp port unreachable`.

Comment: If you have only ohne port forwarding rule, every packet that matches the rule is processed according to this rule. This has nothing to do with how many machines with an ssh daemon you have on your LAN. There can be only one rule with port 22.

Comment: IPv6 is only better if you have public, that means in the internet routed, IPv6 addresses. The you can connect directly to your servers, when there is no firewall rule that blocks access.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They are really comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks to my previous negligence, you have one extra upvote for yourself. (for the "vote them up" comment). All winners here. :)